# record selection limited on 2 selection

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a problem:
in record selection i have to put 3 selections based on parameters, but only first 2 are working:

1

```
if not(isnull({?GNAME})) then (LowerCase ({HSC_REP_YRES_INFOS.NAME}) like "*" & LowerCase ({?GNAME}) & "*" ) else 1=1
```

and

2

```
if not(isnull({?CNAME})) then
    if ({?CFILTER}=1) then
    LowerCase ({HSC_REP_YRES_INFOS.COMPANY_NAME}) like "*" & LowerCase ({?CNAME}) & "*" 
    else if ({?CFILTER}=2) then
    LowerCase ({HSC_REP_YRES_INFOS.TRAVELAGENT_NAME}) like "*" & LowerCase ({?CNAME}) & "*" 
    else if ({?CFILTER}=3) then
    LowerCase ({HSC_REP_YRES_INFOS.SOURCE_NAME}) like "*" & LowerCase ({?CNAME}) & "*" 
    else 1=1
else
    1=1

and
```

3

```
{HSC_REP_YRES_INFOS.YRES_EXPARRTIME}>={?FROMDATE} and {HSC_REP_YRES_INFOS.YRES_EXPDEPTIME} <={?TODATE}
```

if i move the blocks result not change: only the first 2 are working.

someone knows thee problem?

thanks
Mauro

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 formulas for 3 selections and use those in record selection:

Formula1:

```
if not(isnull({?GNAME})) then (LowerCase ({HSC_REP_YRES_INFOS.NAME}) like "*" & LowerCase ({?GNAME}) & "*" ) else 1=1
```

In the same way create other 2 formulas

So your record selection would be:

```
{@formula1}
and 
{@formula2}
and
{@formula3}
```